# Using Username or Email for Devise Causing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I followed the wiki post to add username as another authentication method for Devise.. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Once I completed the steps and tried to sign in I was given this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::SessionsController#create 
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.login: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."login" = 't2kocurek@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
```

As you can see, the create method is looking for a login column. I am not sure why this is happening. I overrode the registrations controller and added the self.find_for_authentication method to it along with the other methods.

Any thoughts?

What code would I need to post to give some more clues?

Comment: do you have a column in your database called login (or perhaps logins)?

Comment: Nope. I added the username column to the users table and the where clause should be checking if that column || the email column matches the login parameter passed in.

Comment: Check devise version, then try renaming find_for_authentication to find_for_database_authentication, since there's this note from that wiki page: Older versions may have called find_for_authentication find_for_database_authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably missed some detail when copying the code. Are you sure you have defined `def self.find_for_authentication`, i.e. a class method? To be double sure, try adding a `raise` inside your method definition and see if the error will appear.

Comment: That was it. After some sleep I relooked over my code and found that I had not been calling find_for_authentication as a class method. Thanks for the help!